# ethers.io library always returns balance of 2.33 ETH

Tags: ethers.js

I am testing the ethers.io and I am trying to read the ETH balance in a metamask wallet.  I use the following code, found on the documentation:

```
 const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
 const connect = async () => {

  await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const balance = await provider.getBalance("ethers.eth");
  console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(balance));
 }
 connect();
```

The issue is that the balance is always 2.337132817842795605 ETH which is NOT what I have in my wallet. Incidentally, it is the same balance found on the ethers library documentation here: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/

Am I missing something? I am using localhost as a server. Is ethers in dev mode on localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please accept my apologies. The code above queries the balance in eth of the Ethers library, not the Metamask wallet of the signer.

Here is the correct code:

```
 const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
 const connect = async () => {
  // Prompt user for account connections
  await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
  let currentBlock = await provider.getBlockNumber();
  console.log(currentBlock);
  const signer = provider.getSigner();
  const address = await signer.getAddress();
  const balance = await provider.getBalance(address);
  console.log(ethers.utils.formatEther(balance));
 }
 connect();
```